# Angular2: angular-http Headers very strange behaviour

Tags: angular, http-headers

I am working on  a very basic angular2 web app and having some issues with http headers...

I have the following function:

```
postStockTake(stockTakeModel: StockTakeModel) : Observable<Response> {
let body = JSON.stringify(stockTakeModel);
      let hd = new Headers();
      hd.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');      
      return this.http.post(ApiUrl, body, {headers: hd})
      .map((res: Response) => res.json())
      .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'server error'));
  }
```

When I omit the hd.append('Content-Type', 'application/json') statement from the headers I actually get a response from the server but it then complains about the payload being in raw format when it should be a json. When I add the 'Content-Type', 'application/json' header it doesn't work at all and I get a "failed to load resource: CONNECTION_RESET" error in my crhome console...
When using a Rest Client I am able to do the post request with the above header with no issues so i'm lost as to why this happens...  I have to add this header for another put request in my app and getting the same results.

When I look under the chrome dev tools networking tab under headers when Omitting the header I see the following headers under Request Headers:

Request headers:
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection: keep-alive
Host: 10.60.160.34
content-type: text/plain
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Referer: http://localhost:4200/settings
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36

When I add the header I get the following under Request Headers in chrome dev tools:

Provisional headers are shown
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Referer: http://localhost:4200/settings
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36

So I don't even see my application/json in the headers when adding it?  Any idea why this would happen/what I could do to fix it?

update: from chrome://net-internals I see the following:

```
http://10.60.160.34/BRMServices/WebEnquiry/StockTake/AddToStockTake
Start Time: 2017-01-13 14:44:30.800
t=19711 [st=0] +REQUEST_ALIVE  [dt=3]
t=19711 [st=0]    URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=0]
t=19711 [st=0]   +URL_REQUEST_START_JOB  [dt=3]
                  --> load_flags = 34624 (DO_NOT_SAVE_COOKIES | DO_NOT_SEND_AUTH_DATA | DO_NOT_SEND_COOKIES | MAYBE_USER_GESTURE | VERIFY_EV_CERT)
                  --> method = "OPTIONS"
                  --> priority = "MEDIUM"
                  --> url = "http://10.60.160.34/BRMServices/WebEnquiry/StockTake/AddToStockTake"
t=19711 [st=0]      URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=0]
t=19711 [st=0]      HTTP_CACHE_GET_BACKEND  [dt=0]
t=19711 [st=0]     +HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST  [dt=1]
t=19711 [st=0]        HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST_STARTED_JOB

 --> source_dependency = 6474 (HTTP_STREAM_JOB)

t=19712 [st=1]        HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST_BOUND_TO_JOB

 --> source_dependency = 6474 (HTTP_STREAM_JOB)

t=19712 [st=1]     -HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST
t=19712 [st=1]     +HTTP_TRANSACTION_SEND_REQUEST  [dt=0]
t=19712 [st=1]        HTTP_TRANSACTION_SEND_REQUEST_HEADERS
                      --> OPTIONS /BRMServices/WebEnquiry/StockTake/AddToStockTake HTTP/1.1
                          Host: 10.60.160.34
                          Connection: keep-alive
                          Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
                          Origin: http://localhost:4200
                          User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36
                          Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
                          Accept: */*
                          Referer: http://localhost:4200/stockTake
                          Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
                          Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
t=19712 [st=1]     -HTTP_TRANSACTION_SEND_REQUEST
t=19712 [st=1]     +HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_HEADERS  [dt=2]
t=19712 [st=1]        HTTP_STREAM_PARSER_READ_HEADERS  [dt=2]
                      --> net_error = -101 (ERR_CONNECTION_RESET)
t=19714 [st=3]     -HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_HEADERS
                    --> net_error = -101 (ERR_CONNECTION_RESET)
t=19714 [st=3]   -URL_REQUEST_START_JOB
                  --> net_error = -101 (ERR_CONNECTION_RESET)
t=19714 [st=3]    URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=0]
t=19714 [st=3] -REQUEST_ALIVE
                --> net_error = -101 (ERR_CONNECTION_RESET)
```

Comment: GET request normaly do not use Content-Type headers but an Accept header. Are you sure that you need to use the Content-Type header here?

Comment: Your code looks fine on the surface. However, it seems you might be running into CORS issues. Is the second request in your question actually a GET or is it an OPTIONS request maybe?

Comment: @MikeOne The second request that's not added to this question where I started to run into this issue was a Post.  This ping request is a get though...  I tried here to replicate the issue i'm having with the Post request in this get request to see if it behaves the same way (which it does...

Comment: When I do the Post request where I initially had this issue without adding this header I actually get a response from the server but When I add the header I don't get anything...  it's like the request is blocked with the header

Comment: Just to make sure. You might tell it to do a POST (or GET), but if there are CORS issues (i.e. cross-domain request of certain types) - the browser itself first does a preflight OPTIONS request (which might not contain your custom set headers). Setting 'Content-type' on a CORS request causes the request to go from a 'simple' request to a 'complicated' request (triggering the preflight OPTIONS). You might be looking at this OPTIONS request instead of the actual request you are expecting. Hence the question.

Comment: @MikeOne It sounds like you're onto something:)  I updated my question with the post example and a log from chrome net internals...  If this is the issue how can I go about resolving it?

Comment: I see that right above the unable to load resource Net::ERR CONNECTION_RESET error I get in the console it says OPTIONS if that helps at all...

Comment: Yes that looks like a preflight. The issue is that you are doing a cross domain request. The 'other' domain needs to set the correct CORS headers in order to allow cross-domain requests for that resource. If you use Angular-cli, you can work around that (during development) by using the build in proxy. Find out more https://juristr.com/blog/2016/11/configure-proxy-api-angular-cli/

Comment: @MikeOne Thanks a lot this was driving me insane for the past 2 days...  Please add that as an answer so I can accept it...  Also please explain to me why the get requests works fine even though that's cross domain as well?

Comment: @MikeOne just one more thing to note.  The backend server is a local server at my work, looking at that blog it seems like the proxy is used to re-route requests to a backend running on another port on the same machine?  So even though this server is on another machine it can still be a CORS issue?

Comment: @user2094257 added it as an answer. Any request that is either a different host, a different protocol (http/https) or a different port is considered to be a Cross domain request :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code looks fine on the surface. However, it seems you might mbe running into CORS issues. Is the second request in your question actually a GET or is it an OPTIONS request maybe?

Just to make sure. You might tell it to do a POST (or GET), but if there are CORS issues (i.e. cross-domain request of certain types) - the browser itself first does a preflight OPTIONS request (which might not contain your custom set headers). Setting 'Content-type' on a CORS request causes the request to go from a 'simple' request to a 'complicated' request (triggering the preflight OPTIONS). You might be looking at this OPTIONS request instead of the actual request you are expecting. Hence the question.

Comment: Thanks again @MikeOne.  So if i'm understanding this correctly the get requests worked before even though it was cross domain because it didn't trigger the preflight headers as I didn't add a content-type header to the request?

Comment: Indeed! That was probably the reason.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the details in the constructor as an object before http

```
hd = new Header({"Content-Type" : "application/json"});
```

Comment: I initially did it like that and got the exact same error which is why I tried it this way...